# Want to make txt files for every png in the folder

Tags: bash, scripts

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash

folder='/home/data/mnist/training'

for filePng in $folder/*
do
touch $filePng.txt
done
```

It works, just that,  for a file named `001.png`, it creates `001.png.txt` instead of `001.txt`.

How can I modify this?

Comment: It's a good habit to get into to quote your variables. Shell script is a weird language that evolved over time rather than being perfectly designed from the get-go, so unfortunately some annoying things like this become necessary. Without quoting your variables, whitespace or asterisks in the variable contents will cause things to break in weird ways. To make your scripts more robust, always surround uses of your variables with double quotes. Here, you would say `for filePng in "$folder"/*` and `touch "$filePng".txt`  - note you only quote them when preceeded by a `$`.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem… Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `basename` command here:

```
touch "$folder/$(basename "$filePng" .png).txt"
```

Note the additional `$folder/`. This is neccessary since the basename command removes the path from.

Comment: Could I suggest that you quoted your parameter expansion and command substitution?

Comment: @TomFenech yeah, probably a good idea to quote the whole string. I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you removed the inner quotes around `$filePng` - they were useful too.

Comment: They would have "unquoted" the variable. Like this: `"This is quoted" This not anymore "This is quoted again"`

Comment: Nope, because `$( )` establishes a new quoting context.

Comment: Oh, you are right - learned something new today ;-)

Comment: I'd typically use backticks (`\``) in a situation like that.

Answer (score 31):

You can remove the existing extension using the shell's [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters) features

> `${parameter%pattern}` The 'pattern' is matched against the end of
>   'parameter'. The result is the expanded value of 'parameter' with the
>   shortest match deleted.

So in your case, replace `$filePng.txt` with `"${filePng%.png}.txt"`

Answer (score 10):

With variation on what steeldriver already mentioned  - parameter expansion - we can use string replacement to do the job. Additionally, you should quote variables. Below is your edited script.

```
#!/bin/bash

folder='/home/data/mnist/training'

for filePng in "$folder"/*
do
    touch "${filePng/.png/.txt}"
done
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have *a lot* of files to create it would be worthwhile to “touch” more than one file at a time, so that you don't need to fork a new process for each of them (which takes quite some time if performed multiple thousand times).

#### Option 1: pattern substitution + `xargs`

This option will supply multiple paths to the `touch` command at once, usually a few thousand or whatever the system can fit on a single command line.

```
find "$folder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png' -print0 |
sed -ze 's/\.png$/.txt/' |
xargs -r0 -- touch --
```

#### Option 2: parameter expansion + command output redirection

This option doesn't run `touch` at all but uses Bash/Bourne/POSIX shell features instead which don't require sub-processes at all.

```
for f in "$folder"/*.png; do
    : >> "${f%.png}.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're confident that you don't have files with `.png` somewhere in the middle of the name, then you can just use an array with parameter expansion:

```
pngs=( /path/to/pngs/*.png )
touch "${pngs[@]/.png/.txt}"
```

This stores all the paths to the files ending in `.png` in an array and then uses parameter expansion to create the list of `.txt` files, by substituting `.png` for `.txt` on each one.

Bear in mind that this will break if you have so many files that they cannot all be passed as arguments to the same invocation of `touch`.